# Ununtu is not booting, I have ubuntu installed in my laptop and then I installed windows 8.1 after it

Tags: system-installation

I have ubuntu installed in my laptop and then I installed windows 8.1 after it in a separate drive but after installation only windows boots not ubuntu when i start my laptop and i am not getting any options to choose from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your boot order in BIOS (usually by hitting F1 or F2, check [here](http://www.cpucare.net/Hardware/BIOS/Access_BIOS.htm)) and make sure that the ubuntu boot manager is the first device under boot priority or boot order, and make sure that the other drive is recognized under that same tab. Once you have those in order save your bios and restart, it should bring up the usual boot manager page.

It would be helpful to know the make of your laptop to be more specific.

Comment: Since OP has a laptop, it seems more likely that ubuntu and windows are both in the same hard drive, but different partitions. If that's the case, then  installing windows after ubuntu probably deleted grub, and that's why OP is "not getting any options to choose from"

Comment: I guess that I was reading into his phrasing "separate drive", it is still worth checking if the boot manager is out of order, but I am more accustomed to installing windows then ubuntu.

Comment: Yes! you were right, I was not aware much of this Grub thing back then. Your answer didn't make any sense earlier but makes perfect sense now. Anyway thank you for answering the question. :]

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that installing Windows first and then Ubuntu works better because the Ubuntu installations helps partitionning the disk very easily.

I tried it the other way too and it didn't work for me neither.